# MKMapview live car tracking

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

My requirement is to create an app that show live tracking of cab. Like famous car apps like Ola , uber and so on.

Please let me know how to update annotation , even for street turn and car reverse . How can simulate moving annotation using MKMapview.  any library i have to use. I searched but i couldn't   find any library

Comment: I recommended you to use google maps SDK for better solutions about this

Comment: @himanth how you are telling that ? . Will apple approve if i use google SK for maps

Comment: Yes of course apple will approve it

Comment: Okay let me integrate then

Comment: How are you tracking the cab location ?

Comment: API will send me location, driver app will update me the cab location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I think the problem is smooth turning of the annotation on the map. As you can place your own custom image instead of the default blue dot.

for smooth turning you can use CMMotionManager as it gives you the acceleration so you can rotate the image by taking the reference of the annotation view. You can update for acceleration data by using update devicemotion data. As you get the [useracceleration](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion/cmdevicemotion/1616149-useracceleration) along x, y and z you can obtain the angle by tan function.This should solve your problem

code for getting the angle

```
[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    double angle = atan(motion.userAcceleration.x/motion.userAcceleration.y);
}];
```

Comment: [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
        double angle = atan(motion.userAcceleration.x/motion.userAcceleration.y);
    }];

Comment: as you get the angle you can rotate it by using nsnotification center or by maintaining the annotation view

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem is quite trivial. If you having problem implementing this library, why not to do it yourself and learn something? You just create some type of Vehicle model class that stores coordinate and previous coordinate. To be able to display it on the map it would have to adhere to MKAnnotation protocol - implement: title, subtitle and coordinate. The newCoordinate position will be set by default upon obtaining position data from network. You need to track two values to successfully animate.

and thus implement something like this:

```
@interface Vehicle : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoordinate;

@end
```

Upon setting the newCoordinate you move the previous value from custom setter into the coordinate property. Once you do this, you would just animate the annotation as usual.

```
// new coordinate obtained from networking
- (void)setNewCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate {

    // implement the value moving part

    _newCoordinate = newCoordinate;
}
```

But be careful when detecting taps on the animated annotation, because of the way it works. Annotation frame will be set when animation starts to the value of finished frame. You would need to hitTest taps on the presentationLayer of the annotation which gets displayed on the Screen during the animation.

To handle the taps override

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}
```

animate with

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0 
                      delay:0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn 
                 animations:^{

} completion:nil];
```

I am sorry but I can't post code here since I have previously implemented this for my employer and am bound by contract.

Comment: Cool thanks . Please let me how to update a smooth move  of animation of annotation. You told me i should override in touches began and hit test . Just let me know what i have to do in that 2 methods